# Construct a bijective function to map arbitrary integer from [1, n] to [1, n] randomly

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, computational-complexity, random

I want to construct a *bijective* function `f(k, n, seed)` from `[1,n]` to `[1,n]` where `1<=k<=n` and `1<=f(k, n, seed)<=n` for each given `seed` and `n`. The function actually should return a value from a *random permutation* of `1,2,...,n`. The randomness is decided by the `seed`. Different `seed` may corresponds to different permutation. I want the function `f(k, n, seed)`'s *time* complexity to be `O(1)` for each `1<=k<=n` and any given `seed`.

Anyone knows how can I construct such a function? The randomness is allowed to be [*pseudo-randomness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness#:%7E:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,much%20online%20and%20other%20security.). `n` can be very large (e.g. `>= 1e8`).

Comment: How about `f(k, n, seed) = (k + seed) % n`?

Comment: @MikeEarnest This has no randomness. Adjacent k will lead to adjacent f(k, n, seed).

Comment: There is some randomness; of the $n!$ bijective functions, there are $n$ possible, one of which is randomly chosen by my function. I agree there is not a lot of randomness, but that is the trade off needed for O(1) time. If there is some requirement you have on the amount of randomness, you should make this clear in your question.

Comment: @MikeEarnest How does your function `randomly` choose one of the `n!` bijective functions? It seems `f(k, n, seed) = (k + seed) % n` can only choose `0,1,...,n-1` or `1,2,...,n-1,0` or `2,3,...,n-1,0,1`, and so on. There're only `n` such bijections, and whatever you choose `seed` to be, these bijections have the same property: adjacent `k` will lead to adjacent `f(k, n, seed)`. This property is far from *pseudo-randomness*.

Comment: This link is the definition of [pseudo-randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness#:~:text=From%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free%20encyclopedia,much%20online%20and%20other%20security.).